# jQuery event to use for browser's auto fill?

Tags: jquery, html

I am having an issue relating to browser's auto suggest for text fields.

Some browsers save your most used email addresses so that when you begin to type them in a text field it comes up with an "auto fill" box.

I cant seem to trigger any sort of event from this box when clicking.

I have provided [**this image**](http://i1297.photobucket.com/albums/ag26/chiggerchug/example_zps2b697c56.png) to show you what I mean (obviously pixelated information) and [**this jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/df6zR/) to demonstrate my point.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#email').bind("keyup change blur click", function() {
        var value = $(this).val();

        if(IsEmail(value))
        {
            $('#emailVerified').fadeIn().html('<img src="http://i1297.photobucket.com/albums/ag26/chiggerchug/tick_zpsa232b56e.png" width="15px" height="15px"/>');
        }
        else
        {
            $('#emailVerified').fadeIn().html('<img src="http://i1297.photobucket.com/albums/ag26/chiggerchug/cross_zpsdbaa8cfa.png" width="15px" height="15px"/>')
        }

    })

})

function IsEmail(email)
{
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    return regex.test(email);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    Email:
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/>
    <div id="emailVerified"></div>
</div>
```

I am able to make the event trigger on keyup and on blur, but I cannot figure out the correct event for the auto fill box.

I should mention that it does work when pressing enter on the auto fill box, you have to actually click the result you want for it to fail.

I would really appreciate some help on this!

Comment: You mean the browsers own autosuggest box.. I don't think there is a way to trigger that with JS.

Comment: sorry @daniel when i take a look on your jsfiddel it works for when i press enter from auto complete browser box. is it not working or your side... Not getting any error here. using chrome.

Comment: @putvande ah I see, fair enough, worth a try!